# How to Create a Plugin after place order to change customer order email

Tags: magento2.4

How to Create a Plugin after placing an order to change  customer order email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `di.xml`

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Quote\Observer\SubmitObserver">
    <plugin name="change_customer_order_email" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\SubmitObserver" />
</type>
```

Create `SubmitObserver.php`

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/SubmitObserver.php

```
 <?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Quote\Observer\SubmitObserver as CoreSubmitObserver;

class SubmitObserver
{
    public function beforeExecute(CoreSubmitObserver $subject, $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

        $email = 'youremail@gmail.com';
        $quote->setCustomerEmail($email);
        $order->setCustomerEmail($email);
        return [$observer];
    }
}
```

Run: **php bin/magento s:d:c**
**php bin/magento cache:flush**

Hope it works for you!

Comment: Thanks its work for me